# Lwuit Create an empty Line between two Containers

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I'd like to create an empty line between to containers embedded in my form
with BoxLayout Y_Axis.

The following piece only shows "test1 test", but I'd like to have

"test1

test2"

or even more lines..

```
import com.sun.lwuit.Container;
import com.sun.lwuit.Display;
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
import com.sun.lwuit.Label;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.BoxLayout;

public class Bug extends javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet {




public void startApp() {

    Display.init(this);

    Container mainContainer = new Container();
    Container current = new Container();
    Form f = new Form();
    f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    current.addComponent(new Label("test1"));
    mainContainer.addComponent(current);
    current = new Container();
    current.setPreferredH(40);
    mainContainer.addComponent(current);
    f.addComponent(mainContainer);
    current = new Container();
    current.addComponent(new Label("test2"));
    mainContainer.addComponent(current);

    f.show();
}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}
}
```

Comment: Let's phrase it different:

form.append("test");
form.append("\n");
form.append("test2");

How can this LCDUI code be translated to LWUIT?

Comment: Fixed now - important to add the Layout not on the form but on mainContainer!

Comment: And to do it properly then:

`Container curLine = new Container();
      curLine.setPreferredH(someFontYouAreUsing.getHeight());
      mainContainer.addComponent(curLine);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use style object for setting margin for first label, like this:

```
Label textLabel = new Label("test1");
Style style = textLabel.getStyle();
style.setMargin(Component.BOTTOM,40);
current.addComponent(textLabel);
```

Comment: Oh my, thank you - I was already modifying Margins manually but I was so focused on "creating a new line" that I didn't see it.

Comment: Seems like I answered to soon.

`current = new Container();
  Label textLabel = new Label("test1");
  Style style = textLabel.getStyle();
  style.setMargin(Component.TOP,40);
  current.addComponent(textLabel);
  mainContainer.addComponent(current);
  f.addComponent(mainContainer);
  current = new Container();
  current.addComponent(new Label("test2"));
  mainContainer.addComponent(current);
`

Neither TOP nor BOTTOM does what I need - the layout still gets arranged side by side, if I don't do some Margin Left or Margin Right which isn't a "true new line", too.

Comment: Yes, it's set Margin, and it's needed to set the layout on mainContainer, not on the form!

Answer (score 0):

add `new Label("")` between container you can give image in Label

Comment: Inserting an Image is probably not the right way to do it.

`current.addComponent(new Label("test1"));
  mainContainer.addComponent(current);
  current = new Container();
  current.addComponent(new Label(" "));
  current.setPreferredH(40);
  mainContainer.addComponent(current);
  f.addComponent(mainContainer);
  current = new Container();
  current.addComponent(new Label("test2"));
  mainContainer.addComponent(current);`

Doesn't do it - and inserting an image sounds wrong.